# Trouble accessing data using ODBC from SQL

Tags: sql-server, mfc, odbc, visual-c++

I am using MFC to retrieve data from a SQL data source using ODBC.
I am having problem in getting data fields other than the "id" field in the  table.
The **varValue** is found to be null for the fields other than "id", in sunsequent iterations.

Please guide me in accessing all the data fields in the table

```
Table data: 

     **id**(nchar)     name(varchar)     age(varchar)

0    **11**                 john            24
1    **22**                 troy            25
2    **33**                 bill            21


only ids are fetched.


    CDatabase db;
    db.OpenEx( NULL, CDatabase::forceOdbcDialog );
    CRecordset rs( &db );
    rs.Open( CRecordset::forwardOnly,
             _T( "SELECT * FROM REPDB.dbo.fellas" ) );

CDBVariant varValue;

short nFields = rs.GetODBCFieldCount( );
while( !rs.IsEOF( ) )
{
   for( short index = 0; index < nFields; index++ )
   {
      rs.GetFieldValue( index, varValue,DEFAULT_FIELD_TYPE );
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess: the issue may be with `DEFAULT_FIELD_TYPE`. Using a plain `CRecordset`, the ODBC API may not be able to determine the type of the field. You can try omitting that parameter and see if you get char array representations of all of the fields, or use `SQL_C_CHAR` instead of `DEFAULT_FIELD_TYPE`, since all of your fields are string types.

You are also missing a call to rs.MoveNext at the end of the while loop.

Another possibility is the use of the cursor library: see this note on the GetFieldValue MSDN page:

> Note: If you declare a recordset object
>   without deriving from CRecordset, do
>   not have the ODBC Cursor Library
>   loaded. The cursor library requires
>   that the recordset have at least one
>   bound column; however, when you use
>   CRecordset directly, none of the
>   columns are bound. The member
>   functions CDatabase::OpenEx and
>   CDatabase::Open control whether the
>   cursor library will be loaded.